# Google Sheets API QPS quota

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am trying to find out the quota limits for google sheet api and google drive api.

I can find most of them here

https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?project=

Then I came across the following documentation https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas

Which states the following for the google analytics apis

> 10 queries per second (QPS) per IP.
>
> In the API Console there is a similar quota which is referred to as "request per 100 seconds per user". By default, it is set to 100 requests per 100 seconds and can be adjusted to a maximum value of 1,000. Despite being listed as "per 100 seconds" the API is restricted to a maximum of 10 requests per second per user.

Is there any QPS limits for google sheets api?
and if it there, if I apply to increase the **request per 100 seconds per user** , my thought is that the QPS should also increase, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the default Quota limit for the Sheets API that you will find in your Developer Console.

[image]

If you want to increase this quota based on the demands on your project, then you need to apply for higher quota. Just click the pencil icon and it will direct you to the link for applying higher quota.

For more information, check this [Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/sheets/limits) of Sheets API.